# Open new form from inside each thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm using the following code to open a new form (that is for user input) in my function:

```
Form4 f4 = new Form4();
f4.mainform = this;
f4.get_Text(matchString);
f4.ShowDialog();
```

It's working perfectly when not threading, but when I try to run the function on two threads I only get 1 form popup. How can I adjust it so that it will support more than one thread?

Comment: A ShowDialog() is used to "Lock" your UI to until that form is handled. If you need multiple forms open you would use Show(). Maybe I'm missing the point.

Comment: I need the UI to lock the thread but i want each thread to display a popup

Comment: You only have one UI. The `ShowDialog` function is specifically used for modal dialog boxes, that is, dialog boxes that lock the application's UI.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  Difficult to think of a situation where your answer is the best way.

Comment: What do you mean you "run the function on two threads"? You're not suggesting that you call `ShowDialog` on the *same* instance from different threads are you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can open a form from any thread, you just need to start a message loop on the new thread, such as:

```
Application.Run(f4)
```

The `Run` method will not return until the form is closed.  It can cause issues, though, so you need to be careful and know what you are doing.  Unless it's a real pain to do, I would sooner consider redesigning your code to be more asynchronous.  For instance, you could create a event handler method to listen for the form's closing event.

Answer (score 0):

The WIN32 Message pump runs on one thread -- the GUI thread.  As soon as you `.ShowDialog()`, the c# stops until the user closes the dialog.  Even if you use `.Show()` to avoid a "stop and wait for the user to push ok", you still must handle all GUI events on the GUI thread by `.Invoke()`ing to the GUI thread.

The way to support multi-threaded-ness is by doing non-GUI work on alternate threads.

Answer (score 0):

`ShowDialog` does pump messages so it would technically work on a separate thread without needing a dedicated message loop. However, what you currently have looks like a recipe for disaster because that form appears to hold a reference to another form via `f4.mainform = this` and it is presumably trying to access it. You simply cannot do this without littering (and I mean that literally) your code with a bunch of `Invoke` or `BeginInvoke` calls.

Furthermore, running UI forms on a thread other than the main UI thread generally does not work well. There are a few obscure problems you can run into. For example, since there would be two UI threads in play it is possible to have 2 active modal dialog boxes open. One might be hidden behind the other and the end user would not see it. This reason, among others, is why it is not generally recommended to use more than one UI thread.

My advice is to figure out a way to make this work with a single UI thread. Your life will be simplier if you do.